# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.1.0) - Customize Login Pages for Developer Portal and Publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to customize the login pages for the dev portal and publisher and I'm referring to the below documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/customizing-login-pages-for-dev-portal-and-publisher/

The 1st step tells to download the Identity Server and in the 2nd step, it says to start up the server using api-manager.sh which could be a mistake.

[image: Steps 1 and 2]

However, I have the following questions related to the scenario.

1. In order to customize the login pages in APIM, should I start up the IS as a key manager as well?
2. Can't we customize the login pages just by using the JSP files readily available in the authentication endpoint in APIM?

Comment: @SomindaGamage Hi Sominda, I went through the doc and that's where the above questions arose. I'm simply asking whether it's necessary to startup the IS as a key manager just to customize the login pages since the APIM does not support SAML configurations as mentioned in the doc.

Comment: In the doc it says to start because it is trying to guide you via a story. If you can customize it directly and they start the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the documentation should be updated. You can use the existing jsp files in the authentication endpoint if you use OAuth2/OpenID. If you are using SAML, then you have to use WSO2 IS as the IDP with WSO2 API Manager.

Some samples can be found in [1].

By default API Manager uses OAuth2/OpenID. You can do the service provider configurations in API Manager. OAuth2/OpenID and SAML use the jsp files used in the authentication endpoint.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/re-branding-the-default-login-page

Comment: Thanks a lot! The issue is login.jsp looking for the relyingParty. Since the SAML configurations are not supported in the wso2am-4.1.0, how is it possible to configure a service provider with the SAML configuration which contains the relyingParty?

Comment: When you do this with OpenID, you get the client Id of the service provider (publisher) as the relying party. You can use the client id for that..  In the case of SAML, you will need to use IS here.. I will update my answer here.